# Installing ndiswrapper-dkms on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel

Every time I try to install ndiswrapper-dkms, I get a crash report saying,

Title: "ndiswrapper-dkms 1.57-1ubuntu1: ndiswrapper kernel module failed to build"

DKMSBuildLog: "DKMS make.log for ndiswrapper-1.57 for kernel 3.8.0-33-generic (x86_64)
 -date and time-

Cannot find kernel build files in

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic

Please give the path to kernel build directory with
the KBUILD= argument to make

make:**[config_check] Error 1**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this problem has been resolved yet. I had a similar issue and followed Chili555's instructions:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967383

The very first one worked for me:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

I also upgraded to 12.04 3.11 after resolving this issue by following these instructions:
http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/07/upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-lts-kernel-to-3-4/

My wifi is behaving erratically (was behaving this way prior to making the above changes) but have not encountered any ndiswrapper issues since.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try 1.58  ndiswrapper 1.58rc1 source code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/testing/

make a folder xxx in home and extract downloaded source code in that

then use

```
cd xxx
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

When it's finished, it'll be installed permanently.

check if it works else its a well known bug well there is a workaround a found , try to install it manually as follows-

1.Download the latest tarball from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/testing/

2.Create the folder /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/

3.Extract it any where and copy it the previously made folder thats /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/   , dont copy the  directory itself , just copy the content.

4.Copy the dkms.conf file from /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.57/ to the /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/ folder as well. Open it with a text editor and change the version of ndiswrapper listed there to 1.58.

5.Run these commands in your console in order to build and install the module using dkms:

```
sudo dkms add ndiswrapper/1.58
sudo dkms build ndiswrapper/1.58
sudo dkms install ndiswrapper/1.58
```

hope it will work. try it if you will get any other problem. Let me know.

Comment: Cannot find kernel build files in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic
Please give the path to kernel build directory with
the KBUILD=<path> argument to make


make[1]: *** [config_check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.58rc1/build/driver'
make: *** [driver] Error 2

Comment: means the problem is still there?

Comment: Seems to be the same problem. I tried reinstalling the linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic package and it didn't help.

Comment: The problem is in the ndiswrapper source, Updating to the newer 1.58rc1 version can fix the bug. thats what i am trying to explain.

Comment: I just did that, and the above was my result. I'd show the whole thing if there wasn't a character limit.

Comment: in the third step, after extracting it anywhere copy the contents of extracted folder and paste it inside the folder we made earlier .

Comment: Copy the dkms.conf file from /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.57/ to the /usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/ folder as well. Open it with a text editor and change the version of ndiswrapper listed there to 1.58.  then go for commands ... try this...

Comment: Once I get to sudo dkms build ndiswrapper/1.58 it says it can't build because of that kernel. Install does the same thing. The dkms part worked, however.

Comment: have you edited dkms.conf file to 1.57??

Comment: wait for one minute i think i got the point

Comment: in usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/  there is a folder named as "folder" go inside that and copy the whole content to usr/src/ndiswrapper-1.58/ .. means the content of "folder" should be present in ndiswrapper-1.58.. it will work..